# ORA-4088, ORA-6512 Using Triggers and RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

While trying to Enforce Foreign Key Integrity in Oracle with Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_IU_SPONSORID_user_registration
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF U_SPONSORID ON user_registration
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE l_SPONSORID VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN 
 SELECT U_SPONSORID 
 Into l_SPONSORID
 FROM U_SPONSOR WHERE U_SPONSORID = :NEW.U_SPONSORID;
 If l_SPONSORID is null
        THEN raise_application_error(-20010, 'Not a valid SPONSORID: '|| ':NEW.U_SPONSORID');
  End if;
 END;
```

I am getting the following errors, while raise error message is not printing

```
ORA-6512: at "BPORTD1.TRG_IU_SPONSOR_USER_REGISTRATION", line 3
ORA-4088: error during execution of trigger 'BPORTD1.TRG_IU_SPONSOR_USER_REGISTRATION'
```

​Any idea of why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Code you wrote has 1.5 mistakes:

- 1st: if there's no such row in `U_SPONSOR` table, `select` won't return `NULL` as you thought, but `no_data_found` you should handle; I presume that's what happened to you
- 0.5th: remove single quotes from `':new.u_sponsorid'` in `dbms_output.put_line` as you'll display literally that, not the ID value.

Sample tables and trigger:

```
SQL> create table u_sponsor (u_sponsorid number);

Table created.

SQL> create table user_registration(u_sponsorid number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_iu_sponsor
  2    before insert or update of u_sponsorid on user_registration
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_sponsorid varchar2 (2000);
  6  begin
  7   select u_sponsorid
  8     into l_sponsorid
  9     from u_sponsor
 10     where u_sponsorid = :new.u_sponsorid;
 11  exception
 12    when no_data_found then
 13      raise_application_error(-20010,
 14        'Not a valid SPONSORID: '|| :new.u_sponsorid);
 15  end;
 16  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing: master row first:

```
SQL> insert into u_sponsor values (200);

1 row created.
```

Two details:

```
SQL> insert into user_registration values (100);
insert into user_registration values (100)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20010: Not a valid SPONSORID: 100
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_IU_SPONSOR", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_IU_SPONSOR'


SQL> insert into user_registration values (200);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

However, I guess you used a trigger to enforce referential integrity just for educational purposes, because - if you want to do that *properly*, create a foreign key constraint. Something like this:

```
SQL> create table u_sponsor (u_sponsorid number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table user_registration(u_sponsorid number references u_sponsor);

Table created.

SQL> insert into u_sponsor values (200);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into user_registration values (100);
insert into user_registration values (100)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C009854) violated - parent key not found


SQL> insert into user_registration values (200);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: I have another question related to this : There's another table "U_PROJECT" from which also I need to validate "PROJECTID" simultaneously in this trigger and print the massage.

Comment: Include yet another SELECT statement into the same trigger. Or, you can create another trigger (just name it differently). However, as I said, you'd rather create a foreign key constraint instead of enforcing referential integrity via trigger(s).

Comment: These master tables are replicated from prod to test Env and due to avoid master data security advised to use this kind of trigger.

Comment: If your data security advised that kind of trigger, then your data security does not understand database functionality.  That would seem to be a big security issue. So is that advice or requirement?

Comment: Hey Belayer, Without foreign key transaction tables won't be able to sync the data so definitely it's a requirement on that basis they suggested to don't use as primary key just check the value by using referencial trigger. could you please elaborate  What would be security issue in this scenario.